# How can I sum filtering data of .csv in D3?

Tags: csv, d3.js

In this .csv file:

```
country,year,sex,num
Argentina,1985,male,150
Argentina,1985,female,240
Argentina,1986,male,100
Argentina,1986,female,200
Brazil,1985,male,10
Brazil,1985,female,140
Brazil,1986,male,45
Brazil,1986,female,48
```

How I can sum the values (150 with 240) of column num, filtering country: Argentina and year: 1985 with d3.js?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are hoping to sum a value whenever country and year are the same - not just for one country and one year at a time:

You can use `d3.nest()` for this, which can allow you to sum a column where the rows share some property, in this case you can sum the `num` column whenever `country` and `year` are the same:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(row) { return row.country; })
    .key(function(row) { return row.year; })
    .rollup(function(values) { return d3.sum(values, function(d) {return +d.num; })  })
    .entries(data);
```

```js
var csv = d3.select("pre").text();

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(row) { return row.country; })
    .key(function(row) { return row.year; })
    .rollup(function(values) { return d3.sum(values, function(d) {return +d.num; })  })
    .entries(data);
    
console.log(nest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre>country,year,sex,num
Argentina,1985,male,150
Argentina,1985,female,240
Argentina,1986,male,100
Argentina,1986,female,200
Brazil,1985,male,10
Brazil,1985,female,140
Brazil,1986,male,45
Brazil,1986,female,48</pre>
```

*I'm parsing a CSV as text, as I cannot load an actual CSV in the snippet.*

The below explains the code, and also demonstrates an alternative structure where the output is a d3.map() rather than an array.

### Grouping Data by Keys

First we can group the data by country, to do so we use `nest().key()`:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(row) { return row.country; })
```

When supplied with some data, the nest works like so:

```js
var csv = d3.select("pre").text();

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(row) { return row.country; })
    .entries(data);
    
console.log(nest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre>country,year,sex,num
Argentina,1985,male,150
Argentina,1985,female,240
Argentina,1986,male,100
Argentina,1986,female,200
Brazil,1985,male,10
Brazil,1985,female,140
Brazil,1986,male,45
Brazil,1986,female,48</pre>
```

The resulting array has one entry per unique key value, in this case one entry per country:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Argentina",
    "values": [
      {
        "country": "Argentina",
        "year": "1985",
        "sex": "male",
        "num": "150"
      },
      {
        "country": "Argentina",
        "year": "1985",
        "sex": "female",
        "num": "240"
      }, ...
```

We can also group by year by creating a second key:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(row) { return row.country; })
    .key(function(row) { return row.year; })
```

Which, if we duplicate the above snippet we get a similar array, now with an additional level:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Argentina",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "1985",
        "values": [
          {
            "country": "Argentina",
            "year": "1985",
            "sex": "male",
            "num": "150"
          },
          {
            "country": "Argentina",
            "year": "1985",
            "sex": "female",
            "num": "240"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "1986",
        "values": [
          {
            "country": "Argentina",
            "year": "1986",
            "sex": "male",
            "num": "100"
          }, ...
```

### Summing Grouped Values

We can also sum values in the lowest level of this nested array using `nest.rollup()`:

```js
var csv = d3.select("pre").text();

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(row) { return row.country; })
    .key(function(row) { return row.year; })
    .rollup(function(values) { return d3.sum(values, function(d) {return +d.num; })  })
    .entries(data);

console.log(nest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre>country,year,sex,num
Argentina,1985,male,150
Argentina,1985,female,240
Argentina,1986,male,100
Argentina,1986,female,200
Brazil,1985,male,10
Brazil,1985,female,140
Brazil,1986,male,45
Brazil,1986,female,48</pre>
```

Which gives us a slightly different result than above, though with the same structure:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Argentina",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "1985",
        "value": 390
      },
      {
        "key": "1986",
        "value": 300
      }
    ]
  } ...
```

### Map results, alternatively

The above structures aren't always ideal if you are trying to look up individual values. We can use `nest.map()` rather than `nest.entries()` to create a [d3 map](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#map) so we can easily access any one value:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(row) { return row.country; })
    .key(function(row) { return row.year; })
    .rollup(function(values) { return d3.sum(values, function(d) {return +d.num; })  })
    .map(data);

console.log(nest.get("Argentina").get("1985"));
```

And here it is in action:

```js
var csv = d3.select("pre").text();

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(row) { return row.country; })
    .key(function(row) { return row.year; })
    .rollup(function(values) { return d3.sum(values, function(d) {return +d.num; })  })
    .map(data);
    
console.log("Argentina, 1985: ",nest.get("Argentina").get("1985"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre>country,year,sex,num
Argentina,1985,male,150
Argentina,1985,female,240
Argentina,1986,male,100
Argentina,1986,female,200
Brazil,1985,male,10
Brazil,1985,female,140
Brazil,1986,male,45
Brazil,1986,female,48</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use D3's inbuilt CSV functions to read the CSV into your program, and then run `reduce` with it to sum up the values. How you get the CSV function will depend slightly on which version of D3 you're using, but for v5, it will be [this D3 sub-library](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch). The code to sum it should look something like this:

```
// put the path to your csv file where I've written 'data.csv'
d3.csv('data.csv').then((data) => {
    const sum = data.reduce((acc, row) => {
        if(row.country === 'Argentina' && row.year === 1985) {
            acc += row.num;
        }
        return acc;
    })
})
```

Your sum will then be in the variable `sum`